# How to internationalize ng-bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker

In my project i use [ng-bootstrap datePicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview).
My datePicker widget is very simple: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/angular/omrmjkgxyje).

But i need internationalize his (needed set russian language). Please help me.

js:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbDate, NgbCalendar} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-range',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-range.html',
  styles: [``]
})
export class NgbdDatepickerRange {

  hoveredDate: NgbDate;

  fromDate: NgbDate;
  toDate: NgbDate;

  constructor(calendar: NgbCalendar) {
    this.fromDate = calendar.getToday();
    this.toDate = calendar.getNext(calendar.getToday(), 'd', 10);
  }

  onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
    if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      this.fromDate = date;
    } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && date.after(this.fromDate)) {
      this.toDate = date;
    } else {
      this.toDate = null;
      this.fromDate = date;
    }
  }

  isHovered = (date: NgbDate) => this.fromDate && !this.toDate && this.hoveredDate && date.after(this.fromDate) && date.before(this.hoveredDate);
  isInside = (date: NgbDate) => date.after(this.fromDate) && date.before(this.toDate);
  isRange = (date: NgbDate) => date.equals(this.fromDate) || date.equals(this.toDate) || this.isInside(date) || this.isHovered(date)
}
```

Comment: in [the page you linked](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview) they speak about internationalization, you need to scroll to 2/3 of the page. And [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ommdpmxrgjq) the demo they link to it

Comment: @jonatjano but it another code structure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok here the solution : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dd3vve?file=app/datepicker-range.ts

what I changed (using [this demo as example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ommdpmxrgjq)):

```
// now class extend NgbDatepickerI18n
export class NgbdDatepickerRange extends NgbDatepickerI18n {
```

.

```
// call to super() in constructor
constructor(calendar: NgbCalendar) {
  super()
```

.

```
// implement the abstract methods
getWeekdayShortName(weekday: number): string {return "td"};
getMonthShortName(month: number): string {return "mt"};
getMonthFullName(month: number): string {return "month"};
getDayAriaLabel(date: NgbDateStruct): string {return "e"};
```

.

```
// provide in component
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-range',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-range.html',
  providers: [{provide: NgbDatepickerI18n, useClass: NgbdDatepickerRange}],
```

you'll need to change the method to return usable values

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from "@angular/common";
import localeRo from "@angular/common/locales/ro";
import localeRoExtra from "@angular/common/locales/extra/ro";

registerLocaleData(localeRo, "ro", localeRoExtra);
```

and then use the provider in the @NgModule decorator:

```
providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "ro-RO"}]
```

There is no need for `NgbDatepickerI18n`!
A working example for German language in Angular for `ngbdatepicker` is on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mezpyn-b6tm1r?file=app%2Fdatepicker-popup.module.ts